# Validate Web Api 2 data before saving it to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question but here is the thing.

I'm creating a Web API 2 webservice where an external application can post data. Before the data is saved to the database I want to validate my data (are all required fields entered, etc.). The datamodel I have to use, does accept any string as itemNumber, so I want to make sure the data is correct. In this case:

- Does the itemNumber exists in the database;
- Is the deliveryType and itemNumber combination a valid combination.

To approach this I have the following (simplified) model to receive data from the POST.

```
public class Product {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [RequiredItem]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

    [RequiredDelivery]
    public string DeliveryType { get; set; }
}
```

My custom attribute 'RequiredItem' is checking the database if the item exists in the database. If not, the response will be a Json message that you need to provide a valid itemnumber.

The attribute 'RequiredDelivery' checks if the combination ItemNumber / DeliveryType is a valid combination (by checking a table where all combinations are stored).

When all the data is correct, I map it to the database model (EF) en write the data to the database.

My question is, if this is a good approach to validate the POST data, or should I do that on an other level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Validation can be done in 2 ways

1. Data Attribute based validation
2. `IValidatableObject`. A general way to have this approach is, create a DTO class(Data Transfer Object) that will contain all the input fields from the user. Create a factory that will convert this DTO into required model(the object that you will use to store data in database). Implement `IValidatableObject` interface for your DTO class. Now, before the request goes into your Controller action, the `Validate` method of `IValidatableObject` will be called. I would prefer this approach over Data Attribute based validation when i need more control over validation.

Then make a validation filter, to return the modelstate that will contain errors with proper status code.

Answer (score 0):

You should validate your data on all level, that means:

- on front-end(to increase UX and application responsiveness)
- on data binding(to make sure that passed data is valid)
- after receiving it on other level(business validation etc.)
- on storing it(proper column types, lengths, keys e.g.)

Remember not to trust any data which comes from user(or outside your API in general).

Basically what I have heard, validation should be performed for each layer/level your system has.